# Como evitar o deslocamento de uma previsão usando ARIMA?

Tags: r, series-temporais, forecast

Criei um modelo de previsão no `R` usando o ARIMA com uma base histórica diária de 2 anos (2018 a 2019). Neste modelo eu uso a Análise Multivariada para criar previsões.

```
    dados = dados_dput

    QTD_PED_TS = as.numeric(dados[,c("QTD_PEDIDOS_PG")])
    QTD_PED_TS = ts(QTD_PED_TS, start = c(2018,1), frequency = 365)

        #Criando Série Temporais

    QTD_PED = as.numeric(dados[,c("QTD_PEDIDOS_PG")])
    QTD_PED = ts(QTD_PED, start = c(2018,1), end = c(2019,334), frequency = 365)

    FL_FDS = as.numeric(dados[,c("FL_FDS")])
    FL_FDS = ts(FL_FDS, start = c(2018,1), end = c(2019,334), frequency = 365)

    FL_DIA_SEMANA = as.numeric(dados[,c("FL_DIA_SEMANA")])
    FL_DIA_SEMANA = ts(FL_DIA_SEMANA, start = c(2018,1), end = c(2019,334), frequency = 365)

    FL_FREE = as.numeric(dados[,c("FL_FREE")])
    FL_FREE = ts(FL_FREE, start = c(2018,1), end = c(2019,334), frequency = 365)

    FL_DIA_MES = as.numeric(dados[,c("FL_DIA_MES")])
    FL_DIA_MES = ts(FL_DIA_MES, start = c(2018,1), end = c(2019,334), frequency = 365)

    #BASE TREINO E TESTE

    QTD_PED_treino = window(QTD_PED, start=c(2018,1), end=c(2019,334))
    QTD_PED_teste = window(QTD_PED, start=c(2019,334))

    #MODELO ARIMA

library(forecast)

QTD_PED_modelo = auto.arima(QTD_PED_treino, xreg = cbind(FL_FDS,FL_FREE,FL_DIA_MES,FL_DIA_SEMANA), trace = T, stepwise = T, approximation = T, seasonal = T)
QTD_PED_Prev = forecast(QTD_PED_modelo, xreg = cbind(FL_FDS,FL_FREE,FL_DIA_MES,FL_DIA_SEMANA), h = 365)

#VISUALIZAÇÃO

plot(QTD_PED_TS)
lines(QTD_PED_Prev$mean, col="red")
```

Nesse meu modelo possui 5 Variáveis: `QTD_PED` (Quantidade de Pedidos) que é a variável principal, `FL_FDS` (Dias com Fim de Semana), `FL_FREE` (Dias com Feriados e Emendas),  `FL_DIA_MES` (Dias do Mês) e `FL_DIA_SEMANA` (Dias da Semana) que são as variáveis secundárias.

Eu gerei minha previsão e validei com os valores reais. Mas percebi que os valores previstos e os valores reais possuíam um deslocamento/defasagem entre uma série e outra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em relação aos Pedidos (o que eu quero prever) a quantidade real é mais baixa no final de semana, porém o meu modelo previu que esse baixo volume de pedidos acontece na quinta e na sexta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Analisando os dados previstos percebi que o meu modelo apesar de ter uma acurácia razoável, ele não conseguiu entender quais dias da semana começa o mês e acabou causando este deslocamento. Eu acrescentei uma variável com os dias do mês e o dia da semana para ajudar meu modelo e apesar de melhorar acurácia, o modelo ainda não consegue acertar os dias da semana.

Minha dúvida é basicamente conceitual, como posso evitar esse tipo deslocamento/ defasagem na minha previsão? Insiro mais alguma variável para que meu algoritmo entenda o comportamento da variável? Ou existe algum outro método que ajuda nesse sentido?

Segue o `dput` com os dados:

```
   dados_dput = structure(list(DT_PAGTO = structure(c(1514764800, 1514851200, 
1514937600, 1515024000, 1515110400, 1515196800, 1515283200, 1515369600, 
1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800, 1515715200, 1515801600, 1515888000, 
1515974400, 1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516320000, 1516406400, 
1516492800, 1516579200, 1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 
1517011200, 1517097600, 1517184000, 1517270400, 1517356800, 1517443200, 
1517529600, 1517616000, 1517702400, 1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 
1518048000, 1518134400, 1518220800, 1518307200, 1518393600, 1518480000, 
1518566400, 1518652800, 1518739200, 1518825600, 1518912000, 1518998400, 
1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 1519344000, 1519430400, 1519516800, 
1519603200, 1519689600, 1519776000, 1519862400, 1519948800, 1520035200, 
1520121600, 1520208000, 1520294400, 1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 
1520640000, 1520726400, 1520812800, 1520899200, 1520985600, 1521072000, 
1521158400, 1521244800, 1521331200, 1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 
1521676800, 1521763200, 1521849600, 1521936000, 1522022400, 1522108800, 
1522195200, 1522281600, 1522368000, 1522454400, 1522540800, 1522627200, 
1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 1522972800, 1523059200, 1523145600, 
1523232000, 1523318400, 1523404800, 1523491200, 1523577600, 1523664000, 
1523750400, 1523836800, 1523923200, 1524009600, 1524096000, 1524182400, 
1524268800, 1524355200, 1524441600, 1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 
1524787200, 1524873600, 1524960000, 1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 
1525305600, 1525392000, 1525478400, 1525564800, 1525651200, 1525737600, 
1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 1526083200, 1526169600, 1526256000, 
1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 1526601600, 1526688000, 1526774400, 
1526860800, 1526947200, 1527033600, 1527120000, 1527206400, 1527292800, 
1527379200, 1527465600, 1527552000, 1527638400, 1527724800, 1527811200, 
1527897600, 1527984000, 1528070400, 1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 
1528416000, 1528502400, 1528588800, 1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 
1528934400, 1529020800, 1529107200, 1529193600, 1529280000, 1529366400, 
1529452800, 1529539200, 1529712000, 1529798400, 1529884800, 1529971200, 
1530057600, 1530144000, 1530230400, 1530316800, 1530403200, 1530489600, 
1530576000, 1530662400, 1530748800, 1530835200, 1530921600, 1531008000, 
1531094400, 1531180800, 1531267200, 1531353600, 1531440000, 1531526400, 
1531612800, 1531699200, 1531785600, 1531872000, 1531958400, 1532044800, 
1532131200, 1532217600, 1532304000, 1532390400, 1532476800, 1532563200, 
1532649600, 1532736000, 1532822400, 1532908800, 1532995200, 1533081600, 
1533168000, 1533254400, 1533340800, 1533427200, 1533513600, 1533600000, 
1533686400, 1533772800, 1533859200, 1533945600, 1534032000, 1534118400, 
1534204800, 1534291200, 1534377600, 1534464000, 1534550400, 1534636800, 
1534723200, 1534809600, 1534896000, 1534982400, 1535068800, 1535155200, 
1535241600, 1535328000, 1535414400, 1535500800, 1535587200, 1535673600, 
1535760000, 1535846400, 1535932800, 1536019200, 1536105600, 1536192000, 
1536278400, 1536364800, 1536451200, 1536537600, 1536624000, 1536710400, 
1536796800, 1536883200, 1536969600, 1537056000, 1537142400, 1537228800, 
1537315200, 1537401600, 1537488000, 1537574400, 1537660800, 1537747200, 
1537833600, 1537920000, 1538006400, 1538092800, 1538179200, 1538265600, 
1538352000, 1538438400, 1538524800, 1538611200, 1538697600, 1538784000, 
1538870400, 1538956800, 1539043200, 1539129600, 1539216000, 1539302400, 
1539388800, 1539475200, 1539561600, 1539648000, 1539734400, 1539820800, 
1539907200, 1539993600, 1540080000, 1540166400, 1540252800, 1540339200, 
1540425600, 1540512000, 1540598400, 1540684800, 1540771200, 1540857600, 
1540944000, 1541030400, 1541116800, 1541203200, 1541289600, 1541376000, 
1541462400, 1541548800, 1541635200, 1541721600, 1541808000, 1541894400, 
1541980800, 1542067200, 1542153600, 1542240000, 1542326400, 1542412800, 
1542499200, 1542585600, 1542672000, 1542758400, 1542844800, 1542931200, 
1543017600, 1543104000, 1543190400, 1543276800, 1543363200, 1543449600, 
1543536000, 1543622400, 1543708800, 1543795200, 1543881600, 1543968000, 
1544054400, 1544140800, 1544227200, 1544313600, 1544400000, 1544486400, 
1544572800, 1544659200, 1544745600, 1544832000, 1544918400, 1545004800, 
1545091200, 1545177600, 1545264000, 1545350400, 1545436800, 1545523200, 
1545609600, 1545696000, 1545782400, 1545868800, 1545955200, 1546041600, 
1546128000, 1546214400, 1546300800, 1546387200, 1546473600, 1546560000, 
1546646400, 1546732800, 1546819200, 1546905600, 1546992000, 1547078400, 
1547164800, 1547251200, 1547337600, 1547424000, 1547510400, 1547596800, 
1547683200, 1547769600, 1547856000, 1547942400, 1548028800, 1548115200, 
1548201600, 1548288000, 1548374400, 1548460800, 1548547200, 1548633600, 
1548720000, 1548806400, 1548892800, 1548979200, 1549065600, 1549152000, 
1549238400, 1549324800, 1549411200, 1549497600, 1549584000, 1549670400, 
1549756800, 1549843200, 1549929600, 1550016000, 1550102400, 1550188800, 
1550275200, 1550361600, 1550448000, 1550534400, 1550620800, 1550707200, 
1550793600, 1550880000, 1550966400, 1551052800, 1551139200, 1551225600, 
1551312000, 1551398400, 1551484800, 1551571200, 1551657600, 1551744000, 
1551830400, 1551916800, 1552003200, 1552089600, 1552176000, 1552262400, 
1552348800, 1552435200, 1552521600, 1552608000, 1552694400, 1552780800, 
1552867200, 1552953600, 1553040000, 1553126400, 1553212800, 1553299200, 
1553385600, 1553472000, 1553558400, 1553644800, 1553731200, 1553817600, 
1553904000, 1553990400, 1554076800, 1554163200, 1554249600, 1554336000, 
1554422400, 1554508800, 1554595200, 1554681600, 1554768000, 1554854400, 
1554940800, 1555027200, 1555113600, 1555200000, 1555286400, 1555372800, 
1555459200, 1555545600, 1555632000, 1555718400, 1555804800, 1555891200, 
1555977600, 1556064000, 1556150400, 1556236800, 1556323200, 1556409600, 
1556496000, 1556582400, 1556668800, 1556755200, 1556841600, 1556928000, 
1557014400, 1557100800, 1557187200, 1557273600, 1557360000, 1557446400, 
1557532800, 1557619200, 1557705600, 1557792000, 1557878400, 1557964800, 
1558051200, 1558137600, 1558224000, 1558310400, 1558396800, 1558483200, 
1558569600, 1558656000, 1558742400, 1558828800, 1558915200, 1559001600, 
1559088000, 1559174400, 1559260800, 1559347200, 1559433600, 1559520000, 
1559606400, 1559692800, 1559779200, 1559865600, 1559952000, 1560038400, 
1560124800, 1560211200, 1560297600, 1560384000, 1560470400, 1560556800, 
1560643200, 1560729600, 1560816000, 1560902400, 1560988800, 1561075200, 
1561161600, 1561248000, 1561334400, 1561420800, 1561507200, 1561593600, 
1561680000, 1561766400, 1561852800, 1561939200, 1562025600, 1562112000, 
1562198400, 1562284800, 1562371200, 1562457600, 1562544000, 1562630400, 
1562716800, 1562803200, 1562889600, 1562976000, 1563062400, 1563148800, 
1563235200, 1563321600, 1563408000, 1563494400, 1563580800, 1563667200, 
1563753600, 1563840000, 1563926400, 1564012800, 1564099200, 1564185600, 
1564272000, 1564358400, 1564444800, 1564531200, 1564617600, 1564704000, 
1564790400, 1564876800, 1564963200, 1565049600, 1565136000, 1565222400, 
1565308800, 1565395200, 1565481600, 1565568000, 1565654400, 1565740800, 
1565827200, 1565913600, 1.566e+09, 1566086400, 1566172800, 1566259200, 
1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 1566604800, 1566691200, 1566777600, 
1566864000, 1566950400, 1567036800, 1567123200, 1567209600, 1567296000, 
1567382400, 1567468800, 1567555200, 1567641600, 1567728000, 1567814400, 
1567900800, 1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 
1568419200, 1568505600, 1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 
1568937600, 1569024000, 1569110400, 1569196800, 1569283200, 1569369600, 
1569456000, 1569542400, 1569628800, 1569715200, 1569801600, 1569888000, 
1569974400, 1570060800, 1570147200, 1570233600, 1570320000, 1570406400, 
1570492800, 1570579200, 1570665600, 1570752000, 1570838400, 1570924800, 
1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 1571270400, 1571356800, 1571443200, 
1571529600, 1571616000, 1571702400, 1571788800, 1571875200, 1571961600, 
1572048000, 1572134400, 1572220800, 1572307200, 1572393600, 1572480000, 
1572566400, 1572652800, 1572739200, 1572825600, 1572912000, 1572998400, 
1573084800, 1573171200, 1573257600, 1573344000, 1573430400, 1573516800, 
1573603200, 1573689600, 1573776000, 1573862400, 1573948800, 1574035200, 
1574121600, 1574208000, 1574294400, 1574380800, 1574467200, 1574553600, 
1574640000, 1574726400, 1574812800, 1574899200, 1574985600, 1575072000, 
1575158400, 1575244800, 1575331200, 1575417600, 1575504000, 1575590400, 
1575676800, 1575763200, 1575849600, 1575936000, 1576022400, 1576108800, 
1576195200, 1576281600, 1576368000, 1576454400, 1576540800, 1576627200, 
1576713600, 1576800000, 1576886400, 1576972800, 1577059200, 1577145600, 
1577232000, 1577318400, 1577404800, 1577491200, 1577577600, 1577664000, 
1577750400, 1577836800, 1577923200, 1578009600, 1578096000, 1578182400, 
1578268800, 1578355200, 1578441600, 1578528000, 1578614400, 1578700800, 
1578787200, 1578873600, 1578960000, 1579046400, 1579132800, 1579219200, 
1579305600, 1579392000, 1579478400, 1579564800, 1579651200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), QTD_PEDIDOS_PG = c(429, 1472, 1473, 
1404, 1432, 1326, 486, 1492, 1369, 1361, 1364, 1310, 697, 667, 
1947, 1878, 1702, 1396, 1511, 834, 737, 2059, 1934, 1739, 972, 
1465, 970, 865, 2339, 2084, 1789, 1885, 1683, 1102, 839, 2085, 
1968, 1766, 1689, 1442, 829, 638, 736, 722, 1543, 1853, 1593, 
1098, 847, 2376, 2081, 2055, 1943, 1542, 1022, 862, 2063, 2207, 
1917, 1874, 1541, 766, 634, 2029, 1731, 1660, 1591, 1439, 767, 
613, 1910, 1730, 1656, 1472, 1760, 865, 753, 2205, 1870, 1977, 
1949, 1792, 1011, 857, 2463, 2188, 1946, 1729, 495, 714, 702, 
2249, 1926, 1729, 1667, 1409, 754, 587, 1919, 1793, 1696, 1739, 
1490, 843, 741, 2080, 1880, 1994, 1885, 1570, 813, 837, 2303, 
2166, 2144, 2157, 1809, 890, 653, 1237, 828, 2169, 1763, 1371, 
795, 728, 1914, 1663, 1657, 1652, 1480, 811, 720, 2055, 1800, 
1759, 1674, 1623, 727, 124, 2435, 2087, 1974, 1778, 1713, 1095, 
1151, 2607, 2333, 1695, 786, 1158, 767, 755, 1988, 1754, 1603, 
1424, 1403, 795, 654, 1916, 1674, 1707, 1586, 1429, 764, 586, 
1995, 1751, 1760, 1635, 890, 845, 2222, 1946, 1610, 1901, 1641, 
889, 602, 1711, 1731, 1579, 1420, 1154, 736, 536, 777, 1780, 
1694, 1621, 1405, 860, 673, 1890, 1730, 1655, 1733, 1538, 942, 
840, 2101, 2044, 1902, 1942, 1723, 994, 908, 2320, 1906, 1903, 
1676, 1272, 800, 722, 1973, 1677, 1718, 1527, 1421, 825, 700, 
2024, 1866, 1681, 1688, 1494, 815, 701, 2174, 1738, 2054, 1968, 
1764, 968, 864, 2526, 2352, 2323, 2128, 1839, 974, 970, 2325, 
1838, 1774, 1557, 625, 773, 665, 2011, 1837, 1810, 1768, 1536, 
794, 882, 2174, 1976, 1965, 1821, 1765, 1058, 936, 2494, 2296, 
2183, 2077, 1759, 932, 817, 2314, 1833, 1839, 1595, 1438, 741, 
739, 1865, 1753, 1639, 1450, 656, 707, 658, 1886, 1864, 1804, 
1760, 1559, 895, 769, 2010, 2074, 1882, 1860, 1876, 893, 912, 
2424, 2137, 1777, 1483, 569, 704, 553, 1910, 1708, 1491, 1514, 
1309, 725, 649, 1794, 1664, 1479, 583, 1007, 686, 614, 1033, 
863, 2064, 1865, 1576, 857, 860, 2080, 1959, 1904, 1804, 1458, 
711, 630, 1683, 1576, 1293, 1361, 1186, 640, 636, 1687, 1466, 
1451, 1404, 1334, 808, 618, 1709, 1543, 1538, 1293, 1194, 655, 
432, 401, 365, 1135, 987, 791, 522, 365, 444, 334, 1084, 1186, 
1092, 995, 1739, 1288, 1064, 1061, 1113, 1118, 773, 640, 1443, 
1327, 1399, 1363, 1219, 702, 657, 1855, 1588, 1608, 1411, 736, 
796, 827, 2194, 2037, 1721, 1616, 1480, 786, 786, 1928, 1732, 
1638, 1589, 1362, 722, 714, 2041, 1852, 1811, 1721, 1506, 694, 
902, 2370, 2287, 1953, 2029, 1916, 1129, 1160, 2657, 2270, 1814, 
1878, 1418, 726, 573, 660, 653, 1413, 1756, 1457, 706, 731, 1871, 
1837, 1715, 1696, 1444, 768, 747, 2086, 1853, 1796, 1698, 1532, 
857, 845, 2252, 2060, 1973, 1896, 1541, 808, 777, 2150, 1761, 
1590, 1482, 1286, 646, 631, 1739, 1655, 1633, 1570, 1416, 716, 
655, 1906, 1795, 1730, 1365, 511, 642, 668, 2200, 1969, 1997, 
2007, 1771, 390, 882, 2269, 1729, 767, 1897, 1360, 665, 599, 
1749, 1488, 1419, 1444, 1223, 675, 623, 1929, 1661, 1647, 1519, 
1380, 721, 736, 2043, 1685, 1927, 1780, 1646, 845, 884, 2437, 
2217, 2024, 2041, 1803, 883, 707, 2094, 1689, 1475, 1433, 1302, 
645, 608, 1747, 1580, 1617, 1529, 1011, 800, 711, 1943, 1672, 
1488, 655, 1136, 718, 747, 2185, 1914, 1803, 1734, 1474, 781, 
684, 1864, 1554, 1488, 1198, 1153, 589, 413, 950, 616, 1552, 
1396, 1278, 764, 614, 1791, 1518, 1526, 1451, 1357, 762, 674, 
1936, 1855, 1730, 1788, 1616, 894, 821, 2188, 1954, 1856, 1653, 
1278, 652, 592, 1887, 1582, 1544, 1517, 1293, 753, 590, 1911, 
1788, 1620, 1611, 1494, 798, 706, 2001, 1746, 1695, 1807, 1582, 
865, 826, 2312, 2162, 1718, 2058, 1647, 894, 740, 2051, 1799, 
1671, 1372, 1061, 596, 578, 1886, 1634, 1536, 1557, 1430, 762, 
690, 2047, 1952, 1853, 1822, 1568, 911, 767, 2138, 2111, 2046, 
1990, 1737, 875, 700, 2156, 2055, 1712, 1587, 1379, 728, 599, 
1794, 1749, 1619, 1526, 1408, 618, 611, 1781, 1554, 1666, 1589, 
1505, 827, 613, 1935, 1817, 1897, 1936, 1794, 934, 777, 2338, 
2096, 1950, 1875, 1622, 645, 610, 2007, 1646, 1547, 1428, 1329, 
733, 586, 1748, 1660, 1634, 1443, 538, 693, 658, 1932, 1555, 
824, 1788, 1607, 835, 740, 2075, 1944, 1948, 1746, 1544, 847, 
597, 1790, 1544, 1441, 1277, 1166, 719, 529, 1592, 1392, 1467, 
1511, 1313, 778, 638, 1756, 1581, 1559, 1419, 1285, 678, 507, 
1021, 482, 370, 1005, 923, 506, 401, 735, 498, 291, 1008, 857, 
497, 555, 1554, 1315, 1318, 1329, 1183, 689, 555, 1684, 1501, 
1505, 1505, 1350, 800, 667, 1827, 1428, 1832), FL_FDS = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), FL_FREE = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FL_DIA_MES = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22
), FL_DIA_SEMANA = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -751L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Manda o `dput()` dos dados usados por favor para podemos ajudar

Comment: Olá @TomásBarcellos estou com dificuldades em fazer o dput. O R me mostra a mensagem de erro: "Error in dput(dados_base, 50) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection." Não sei como corrigir isso.

Comment: Seria `dput(head(dados_base, 50))`. O `dput` recebe só um argumento. O `head(x, 50)` é para deixar a base menor.

Comment: Puts verdade. Me enrolei, agora foi.

Comment: Os dados do dput não são os mesmos dados do modelo. Exemplo, não tem `QTD_USU` e o dia da semana está por extenso e não `FL_DS`, etc..

Comment: É que quando fui criar as Séries Temporais eu renomeei, mas eu vou corrigir para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Atualizei o modelo com as variáveis da minha base de dados. O problemas que estou tendo que no fim de semana tem baixo nível de pedidos, ou seja, com os valores reais o sábado e domingo tem poucos pedidos, porém na minha previsão os dias que possuem poucos pedidos estão na quinta e na sexta. Tem esse deslocamento de dias que não consigo corrigir.

Comment: Erro: `auto.arima can only handle univariate time series`. Usa o [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) para reproduzir o erro, por favor.

Comment: Essas variáveis são séries temporais, acrescentei o código para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Por favor, use o reprex para gerar o exemplo, cada vez tem um erro diferente. Agora tenho `Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'` ao rodar a linha que gera `QTD_PED_teste`

Comment: Estou tentando pesquisar sobre Reprex, mas não tenho a mínima ideia de como usá-lo, preciso de um exemplo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103579/discussion-between-izak-mandrak-and-tomas-barcellos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível evitar este deslocamento. Ele é uma característica inerente dos modelos ARIMA(p,d,q). Em particular, dos modelos AR(p), que fazem parte dos modelos ARIMA(p,d,q).

[ARIMA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARIMA) é a sigla, em inglês, para **A**uto**r**egressive **I**ntegrated **M**oving **A**verage. Ele é a generalização dos modelos ARMA(p,q) (**A**uto**r**egressive **M**oving **A**verage), justamente para lidar com os casos em que ocorre não-estacionariedade da série temporal.

O modelo ARMA, por sua vez, é a união de outros dois modelos: o modelo AR(p) e o modelo MA(q). O modelo AR(p) (ou seja, o modelo AR de ordem p) tem uma fórmula específica, dada por

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que a observação X_t do modelo AR(p) é dada pela combinação linear das p observações anteriores X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, ..., X_{t-p}, mais uma constante *c* e mais a variável aleatória epsilon_t. Dessa forma, todo modelo AR(p) vai exibir esse deslocamento, pois a observação atual é decorrente da combinação linear das p observações anteriores. Querer que isso não ocorra ao usar um modelo autorregressivo é como usar a equação y = a*x + b e não querer que apareça uma reta.

Como exemplo final, veja essa pesquisa feita no Google Imagens por [ar model fitted values](https://www.google.com/search?q=ar+model+fitted+values&sxsrf=ACYBGNSH0aL--xfMWjpu8b5rEx9APX72RA:1579826436513&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0hbiMgJvnAhUVHbkGHWVaCf0Q_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1280&bih=666). Sempre ocorre este deslocamento quando há uma comparação entre os valores observados e os previstos.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @Marcos Nunes! Tu ta me salvando mais uma vez! Eu tenho mais uma pergunta, se esse deslocamento sempre ocorre, na validação com o valor previsto e real eu posso alinhar manualmente?

Comment: Vou te responder com outra pergunta, com opções A e B. O que é mais indicado? **Opção A:** usar o método Box-Jenkins, descrito em 1970 e que é padrão na análise de séries temporais há 50 anos, sem interação humana nos resultados numéricos ou **Opção B:** mexer manualmente nos resultados dele, manipulando o que foi obtido sem conhecimento profundo sobre a matemática que está por trás disso?

Comment: Como matemático escolheria a opção A. Então o Box-Jenkins é o método que faz esse encaixe?

Comment: Eu não sei exatamente o que significa "encaixe" neste contexto.

Comment: Desculpa já estou começando a pesquisar sobre Box-Jenkins. A palavra correta seria ajuste. O Box-Jenkins é o método que faz o ajuste do modelo?

Comment: Não só o ajuste, mas também ajuda a decidir qual é o melhor modelo para os dados.

Comment: Entendi @Marcos Nunes obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, eu vejo que me falta aprofundar na área de estatística e vejo necessidade estudar mais sobre isso. Em uma outra pergunta você me indicou um livro (Brockwell e Davis), mas por ele ser em inglês dificulta pra mim. Você conhece algum outro livro ou artigo que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103664/discussion-between-izak-mandrak-and-marcus-nunes).